# How can I obtain ObjectSet<T> from Entity-Framework at runtime where T is dynamic?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

(Note, the code below are just examples. Please don't comment on the why this is necessary. I would appreciate a definitive answer of YES or NO, like if it is possible then how? If not it's fine too. If the question is vague let me know also. Thanks!)

Example, I can get ObjectSet<*T*> below:

```
ObjectSet<Users> userSet = dbContext.CreateObjectSet<Users>();
ObjectSet<Categories> categorySet = dbContext.CreateObjectSet<Categories>();
```

The code above works okay. However, I need the entity table to be dynamic so I can switch between types. Something like below.

```
//var type = typeof(Users);
var type = typeof(Categories);
Object<type> objectSet = dbContext.CreateObjectSet<type>();
```

But the code above will not compile.

[EDIT:]
What I'd like is something like, or anything similar:

```
//string tableName = "Users";
string tableName = "Categories";
ObjectSet objectSet = dbContext.GetObjectSetByTableName(tablename);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use the example here in [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

```
var type = typeof(Categories); // or Type.GetType("Categories") if you have a string
var method = dbContext.GetType.GetMethod("CreateObjectSet");
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
generic.Invoke(dbContext, null);
```

Answer (score 6):

I've got this working with the following tweak to the suggestions above:

```
var type = Type.GetType(myTypeName);
var method = _ctx.GetType().GetMethod("CreateObjectSet", Type.EmptyTypes);
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
dynamic objectSet = generic.Invoke(_ctx, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here, http://geekswithblogs.net/seanfao/archive/2009/12/03/136680.aspx. This is very good because it eliminates having multiple repository objects for each table mapped by EF particularly for mundane operations like CRUD, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That is why this was absolutely OT: "Please don't comment on the why this is necessary." If you just described why it is necessary you could have that answer immediately. Also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625746/generic-repository-with-ef-4-1-what-is-the-point/5626884#5626884 Generic repository is incorrect pattern - it is useful only as a base for specific repository: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110981/the-repository-itself-is-not-usually-tested Related questions are about DbContext API but it is same with ObjectContext API.