# entity framework 4.1 faking dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Im using the entity framework 4.1 and have followed a tutorial to fake the dbcontext to mock and do unit tests.  Everything works as expected with this.  ive amended the original dbcontext to return idbset's however when i recreated my model it overwrote this.  This is to be expected i suppose but wondered whether there is away i can stop this happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us some code sample, specially how you are mocking the dbcontext. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you even try to mock context? It is wrong approach because it [will not help you to test your code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766478/unit-testing-dbcontext) and according to [this interesting article](http://www.davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html) (I got reference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110981/the-repository-itself-is-not-usually-tested/7111748#7111748)) you should not mock types you don't own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest approach is to replace the T4 templates that do the code generation with your own – copy the default templates into your project and adapt them to generate the code you want.

MSDN has an introduction: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520

Answer (score 0):

You can also use moles. But I like the t4 template better.