# How to implement "GenericRepository" for implement Objects to SQL Linq layer? I am working on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern, asp.net-4.0

I need to implement a generic repository (reuseable .dll) for applying operations ( e.g update, insert, delete, search ) keeping the fact we can make complex queries from database containing multiple joins and complexity.

I am doing in this way

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
//internal SchoolContext context; which context I need to use to behav as generic(.dll)
internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

   public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context) //that won't be this context
   {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
   }
   .... public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity){..}
   .... public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete){..}
   .... public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate){..}
 }
```

So, which context, somehow to achieve the same working of DBContexts (i.e to interact with DB from objects using LINQ)?

Secondly,
I am using some specific classes ( in case when this generic repository don't fulfills my operational requirement ) like some huge complex query. 
like

```
  class StudentRepository : GenericRepository
  {

  }
  class PersonRepository : GenericRepository
  {

  }
```

...
Is this way is right or some other good implementation is available ?

Regards
Usman

Answer (score 2):

Using specific repository is correct way because it encapsulate specific data access logic for given entity type / aggregate root. Using generic repository itself is not correct way because it [doesn't bring any additional value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625746/generic-repository-with-ef-4-1-what-is-the-point/5626884#5626884). It is just wrapper for EF `DbSet` which already [is "generic repository"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110981/the-repository-itself-is-not-usually-tested/7113827#7113827) and it still have all problems related to `IDbSet` / `DbSet`. If your main target is to make your code testable [you will not achieve that with generic repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904139/fake-dbcontext-of-entity-framework-4-1-to-test/6904479#6904479) exposing `IQueryable` (to allow complex queries and joins not hidden by the repository).

Comment: No!! I want to use this in some generic way.